# KVL not satisfied during simple diode series

Tags: diodes, voltage-measurement

A power diode in the reverse biased position is connected in series to a 2.5Mohm resistor.  The voltage source is connected in series to these two components and is set at 10V dc.  The voltage across the diode is 7.5V while the resistor is ~0V.  Where did the "missing" voltage go?

Comment: Were you measuring the diode voltage and the resistor voltage at the same time? What is the equivalent resistance of your voltmeter?

Comment: The diode and resistor voltage together was 10V dc.  I will check the equivalent resistance of the voltmeter. But why would the resistance of the voltmeter affect the voltage thru the resistor in series with the diode. If both resistors (voltmeter and circuit) are in parallel then their voltages should be the same.

Comment: Given a choice between KVL and measurement error, I'm going to go with measurement error.

Comment: Would it disprove the latter if I uploaded pictures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your voltmeter has an input resistance of 7.5M ohms, that would give the results you see.

Each time you connect to the circuit you are placing that resistance in parallel with the component.

So when measuring across the diode 1uA will flows and you see the voltage divider action.

But when measuring across the 2.5M resistor the diode stops all current, so that is why you see 0v.

Try modeling the equivalent circuit.

(Credit to Photon as he hinted to this in the first comment).

Comment: Oh I get it.  So when the voltmeter is placed in parallel with the diode, current flows thru the voltmeter's resistor causing the drop in voltage.  When I place the voltmeter in parallel with the resistor, no current is allowed thru, hence the 0V. Awesome, thank you!!!